# How do I get all the childs of each squad?

Tags: unity, c#

```
var squads = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Squad");
        for(int i = 0; i < squads.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach(Transform squadMember in squads[i])
            {
                squadMembers.Add
            }
        }
```

squadMembers is List

Comment: Can you clarify, is this exactly the code you've written? Or does your `Add` line continue as `squadMembers.Add(squadMember)`? Is this not getting the result that you expect? How do the current results differ from what you want?

Comment: Working I had to do squads[i].transform in the foreach loop

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an Answer then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution I had to add a transform in the foreach loop:

```
squads[i].transform
```

The code:

```
private List<Transform> squadMembers = new List<Transform>();

  Start()
  {
    var squads = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Squad");
            for(int i = 0; i < squads.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach(Transform squadMember in squads[i].transform)
                {
                    squadMembers.Add(squadMember);
                }
            }
  }
```

Comment: Why having a second foreach loop since a GameObject can and will only have one transform attached to it ?
you can replace those 4 lines with:

squadMembers.Add(squads[i].transform);

Comment: @OmarGuendeli using `foreach(Transform squadMember in squads[i].transform)` will loop over all immediate children of that transform.

Comment: @Eddge don't you think it's overkill ? as this is like a GetComponentsInChildren<Transform> and will recursively loop among all the transforms, let's stay those childs have rigged meshes with multiple bones.

Comment: @OmarGuendeli `GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>` will get all those multiple bones, this foreach loop will only get the immediate children, the top layer, not their children(So not the bones).

Comment: @OmarGuendeli however using `GetComponentInChildren<Transform>` will essentially do the same thing as this foreach loop  `GetComponentsInChildren` and `GetComponentInChildren` do 2 different things.  I will stay say this loop is probably alot less expensive then the getComponentInChildren, as one is just looping over the transforms it already knows exist while the other appears to be doing a getComponent<> call on each child to get its transform.  Only way to really test is create a large project with hundreds of children and use the built-in tools to check performance.